# FillEllipse Error

Tags: c#, exception, graphics, drawing, ellipse

I get a **JIT compiling error** running this code

```
void draw(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     Graphics gr =this.CreateGraphics();
     Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
     int x = 50;
     int y = 50;
     int width = 100;
     int height = 100;
     gr.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, width, height);
     gr.Dispose();
     SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
     gr.FillEllipse(brush, x,y,width,height);
 }
```

Error says: ***System Argument Exception: Invalid argument in 
FillEllipse(Brush, int32 x,int32 y,int32 width,int 32 height);***

Comment: You do realize you are actually disposing the `Graphics` object and then attempting to use it again, do you?

Comment: ah sorry , I mention it after posting sorry, but now i have another question, how to make form size static in different monitors? by different dimensions? sorry and thank you

Comment: It is almost always a mistake to use `CreateGraphics`.  Your `draw` method has a `PaintEventArgs` passed into it which I assume you get from a `Paint` event of some sort.  You should use the Graphics instance that comes from that:  `Graphics gr = e.Graphics`.  And don't Dispose it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing in the `PaintEventArgs e` you can and should use its `e.Graphics`!

And since you didn't create it, don't dispose of it!

But those `Pens` and `Brushes` you create you should disposed of or better yet, create them inside a `using` clause! For the `SolidBrush` we can use the standard `Brush`, which we can't change and must not dispose of either!

To be sure the Fill won't overwrite the Draw I have switched the order.

So, try this:

```
void draw(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
     int x = 50;
     int y = 50;
     int width = 100;
     int height = 100;
     gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, x, y, width, height);
     using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5) )
        gr.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, width, height);
 }
```